# Convergence of a series with repeated sines

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Show that the series 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\big(\sin(n)\big)}{n},
$$
converges.

More generally, show that for every $k\in\mathbb N$ the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sigma_k(n)}{n},
$$
converges, where $\sigma_1(x)=\sin(x)$ and $\sigma_{k+1}(x)=\sin\big(\sigma_k(x)\big)$.

**Note.** I am looking for an elementary proof, if such is available. I do know that such elementary proof exists, for $k=2$, since that case was  qualifying exam (University of Adelaide) a few years ago. On the other hand, I know of a non elementary proof (for $k$ general), using the nontrivial fact that $\dfrac{1}{2\pi}$ has finite [irrationality measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrationality_measure#Irrationality_measure). I imagine that any proof would have as a first step establishing the fact that the sequence
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_k(j), \quad n\in\mathbb N, 
$$
is bounded.

**Update.** Actually, using advanced tools (i.e., irrationality measure), 
it turns out that even
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sigma_k(n)}{n^a},
$$
converges, for every $a>0$, and $k\in\mathbb N$,
while the same tools can not determine whether
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\big(\sin(\beta n)\big)}{n^a},
$$
converges, for every $\beta$.

Comment: What does "finite irrationality measure" mean?

Comment: Irrationality measure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrationality_measure#Irrationality_measure

Comment: Ah, that explains it, thnx.

Comment: $\sin x<x\iff\sin(\sin x)<\sin x$. (You can verify this geometrically, by noticing that the arc *x* is larger than the chord, which itself is larger than the sine, as the former is the hypotenuse, and the latter is the leg). Then use the fact that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin n}n$ [converges to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Trigonometric_functions) $\dfrac{\pi-1}2$, which you can prove by using either [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula), or the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Comment: Achtung, @Lucian: $\sin(\sin x)<\sin(x)$ only if $\sin x> 0$, i.e. only if $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{\pi}\right\rfloor$ is even!

Comment: Taking $A_k(n):=\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_k(j)$ and $\phi(t):=\frac{1}{t}$ in Abel's summation formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) it is
enough to prove that $\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_k(j)=O\left(\frac{n}{\log^2 n} \right)$. I don't know it helps, but to transform a  sum to an integral generally easier to estimate.

Answer (score 8):

To prove the convergence it is sufficient to show that
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(kn)}{n}\right|= \left|\frac{\pi-k}{2}+\pi \left\lfloor\frac{k}{2\pi}\right\rfloor\right| < \frac{\pi}{2} \tag{1}$$
by regarding the LHS as the imaginary part of a geometric series and by applying Abel's lemma.

Then we have that the Fourier coefficients of $\sin(\sin x)$ decay pretty fast since $\sin(\sin x)\in C^3([-\pi,\pi])$. If we are allowed to write $\sin(\sin x)$ as its Fourier series and to switch the sums (**this is crucial**) we have:
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\sin n)}{n}\right|\leq K\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\pi}{k^2},$$
for istance. **I am expecting** that the same holds for $\sigma_k(x)$, since, in general, if $f(x)$ is an odd periodic function belonging to $C^{3}(\mathbb{R})$ **and we are allowed to switch sums**,
$$\sum_{n=1}\frac{f(n)}{n}$$
converges because the $k$-th Fourier coefficient of $f(x)$ is $o(k^{-2})$ and $(1)$ holds.

By using Bessel functions we can write:
$$\sin(\sin n)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}2\cdot J_{2k+1}(1)\sin((2k+1) n),\tag{2}$$
where the convergence is uniform, but now we have to justify the sum-switch procedure. This is more-or-less the same as proving that the partial sums of $\sin(\sin n)$ are bounded. Exploiting $(2)$ we get:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}\sin(\sin n)\leq\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\cdot J_{2k+1}(1)}{|\sin(k+1/2)|},$$
and we have to prove that the RHS is bounded. If we define $\|x\|$ as the distance between $x$ and the closest integer, we have:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{K}\frac{2\cdot J_{2k+1}(1)}{|\sin(k+1/2)|}\leq \sum_{k=0}^{K}\frac{1}{4^k(2k+1)!\cdot|\sin(k+1/2)|}\leq \sum_{k=0}^{K}\frac{1}{2^{2k+1}(2k+1)!\cdot\left|\frac{2k+1}{2\pi}\right|},$$
so, in order to prove that the partial sums of $\sin(\sin n)$ are bounded, it is sufficient to prove that there exists a positive number $C$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{2k+1}{2\pi}\right|\geq\frac{C}{(2k+1)!},\tag{3}
$$
holds for every $k$. This is much weaker than requiring that $2\pi$ has a finite irrationality measure: if the terms of the continued fraction of $2\pi$ do not grow too fast, since
$$\frac{1}{(a_n+1)q_n^2}<\frac{1}{q_{n}(q_{n+1}+q_{n})}<\left|2\pi-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|<\frac{1}{q_n q_{n+1}}<\frac{1}{q_n^2},
$$
holds for every convergent $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ of $2\pi=[a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots]$, $(3)$ follows from the Legendre theorem.

Comment: You have written "This gives:
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\sin n)}{n}\right|\leq K\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{k}{k^3},$$
for istance." - How did you get that? Also, note that the ratio$$\frac{\sigma_{k+1}(x)}{\sigma_k(x)}$$ can be negative.

Comment: Simply write $\sin(\sin n)$ as a Fourier series and use the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(kn)}{n}=\frac{\pi-k}{2}=O(k)$. Moreover, $\frac{\sigma_{k+1}(x)}{\sigma_{k}(x)}$ cannot be negative on $[0,\pi/2]$ since $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is non-negative on $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: @Jack This is really cool; it took me a moment, though, to flesh out the core assertion you make at the beginning of your answer, namely, $\sum_{n\geq1}f(n)/n$ converges whenever $f$ is an odd periodic function in $C^4(\mathbb R)$. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like you're suggesting we write $f(x) = \sum_{k\geq1}c_k\sin{(kx)}$, where $c_k=o(k^{-3})$, and then interchange the order of summation: $\sum_{n\geq 1} f(n)/n = \sum_{k\geq1}c_k\sum_{n\geq1}{\sin{(kn)}\over n}$. The change is justified because $\sum_{n\geq1}{\sin{(nx)}\over n}$ converges uniformly. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @Nick Strehlke: exactly. The next step is to prove that: $$\mathcal{S}_k=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sigma_k(n)}{n}=-\frac{1}{2}+O\left(k^{-1/2}\log k\right)$$ by using the inequality $\sigma_{k}(x)\leq\min\left(\sin(x),\sqrt{\frac{3}{k}}\right)$ that is also very nice.

Comment: @Jack Actually, I just realized that $\sum_{n\geq1}{\sin{(nx)}\over n}$ doesn't converge uniformly (it converges to a discontinuous function, namely, $-\operatorname{arg}(1-e^{ix})$). Nor does $\sum_{n\geq1}{\sin{(nk)}\over n}$ converge absolutely when $k$ is an integer. So how do we justify the change in order of summation that leads to $\sum_{n\geq 1}f(n)/n = \sum_{k\geq 1}c_k\sum_{n\geq1} {\sin{(kn)}\over n}$?

Comment: Ouch. This is a major issue :/

Comment: So we have $\left|\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(k n)}{n}\right|<\pi$ that is better than $O(k)$, but we really need something else to justify the exchange of sums. Is someone willing to fix this? The lack of uniformity is only due to the $k$s that are close to an integer multiple of $\pi$, but they cannot be "too many", since, as already pointed by the author, $\pi$ has a finite irrationality measure.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)$ is an odd continuous function with range $[-a,a]$, and $f(x) \leq |x|$,  then $f^k(x)$ has the same property for all $k \geq 1$.

If a sequence $a_n$ has a symmetric (even) frequency distribution measure in the interval $[-a,a]$, then $f^k(a_n)$ has the same property.

Based on this, and taking $a_n$ to be the value of $(n \mod 2\pi)$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$, by Abel summation the $\sum \frac{f^k(a_n)}{n}$ converges if $s_n = f^k(a_1) + \dots + f^k(a_n)$ is $O(n^c)$ for $c < 1$.  Uniform distribution modulo $1$ gives only $s_n = o(n)$ which is an epsilon less than what we need.

The difference $d_n = |\frac{s_n}{n} - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f^k(x) dx|$ converges to $0$ by uniform distribution (applied to $f^k \circ g$ for $g$ that re-coordinatizates the interval to make the distribution uniform). For $f^k$ of bounded variation,  we are asking a special case of the discrepancy problem for sequence $a_n$ : is there a bound $d_n = O(n^{-u})$ for $u > 0$?

This power-of-$n$ improvement in the convergence is true for any sequence with a positive irrationality measure.  Maybe a sledgehammer but it shows the problem does not need any special property of $f(x)=\sin x$ except that $f^k$ have bounded variation (which holds if $f'$ exists and is continuous).

Answer (score 0):

I could be totally wrong, but it seems to me that the analysis in [de Bruijn's book](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s24/sh/8f38bda7-c914-4c19-bb78-d411de0bb8d6/167a04a1d7c8d16e8b2fe44080830f57), p. 157(see, esp, a couple of pages down, like p. 159, where the $x$ dependence is discussed) would seem to indicate that the series would diverge for large $k,$ at least.

Comment: Actually, it converges for every $k$, due to the fact that the measure of irrationality of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ is finite. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150863/does-equidistribution-of-zero-average-due-to-irrationality-imply-boundedness.

Comment: I must be dense -- I don't see how the answer to this question follows from the one you are pointing to.

Comment: It follows since $f(x)=\sigma_k(x)$ is $C^\infty$, $2\pi$-periodic and of zero average, and $1/2\pi$ has finite irrationality measure. Therefore, $s_n=\sigma_k(1)+\sigma_k(2)+\cdots+\sigma_k(n)$ is a bounded sequence, for every $k$, due to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150863/does-equidistribution-of-zero-average-due-to-irrationality-imply-boundedness, and by Abel summation method, the above series converges.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. $k$ is fixed, while in the Bruijn's book $k\to\infty$.

Comment: @vesszabo no, I did not misunderstand.

Comment: Then could you explain clearly what you mean? I don't understand your answer, and it seems I am not the only one.

Comment: @D.Thomine: Please be more specific. What do you want me to explain?

Comment: @Yiorgos S.Smyrlis: actually, my comment was for Igor Rivin.